# Why does Firefox not clear "Connecting..." message after JSON data request?

Tags: json, firefox, jsonp

Under FireFox 4.0 or 5.0, I create a request for JSON data with the following code:

```
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.src = url;
        document.body.appendChild(script);
```

The JSON data arrives, my JSON handler processes it, but the "Connecting..." message in the tab remains forever.  I also verified that Firefox closes the TCP connection afterwards.   IE handles this normally.  How can I indicate to the browser that the request has been completed so that the tab returns to a normal status?

Comment: FF is going downhill... used to be my fav.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have to explicitly call `document.close()` in FF.

If you're using `iframe` then you will need to call `document.close()` on the `iframe` window.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is some issue with FF 4/5, tabs showing connecting most of the time. It is not that there is any issue in your code but problem with the browser. Take a look [at this topic on the Mozilla help site](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/questions/806167) which blames an add-on called "[TabRenamizer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tabrenamizer/)". If you are open to use `jQuery` then we can have some alternative to try and see.